# How do I get past these letters that require camera light?

Tags: assassins-creed-3-liberation

I keep opening these letters throughout the game and a little message pops up repeatedly at the right saying "Direct the rear camera toward a bright light." I do so, and nothing happens. I really don't understand what else I can do. It seems like I do this for like 10 minutes before it randomly decides to let me turn the circular thing. What the hell am I doing wrong? This feature has been *extremely* frustrating.

Comment: It is possible that this is some sort of bug you are encountering or that your camera is broken, generally in my experience pointing the rear camera to any light source was adequate to allow the mini game to detect the light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had trouble with this one as well.

What you're missing is once you're pointing at a bright enough source, **you need to turn your Vita around, like a steering wheel** (spinning the screen) until you see the small handle you need to turn.

This is mentioned *somewhere* along the game, but isn't very clear during this so-called mini-game.

Comment: Perfect! Just got another one of these, tried this, and it took me like 10 seconds. That would be a very useful thing to tell people from the get-go...